# Ошибка с добавлением видео через ссылку

Tags: html

Код:

```
<h1 align="center">Лучшее видео недели!</h1>
        <br />
        <p style="text-align: center;">
        <object width="470" height="353">
        <param name="movie" value="https://vk.com/video-53845179_456239810">
        <param name="wmode" value="window">
        <param name="X-Frame-Options" value="allow">
        <embed src="https://vk.com/video-53845179_456239810" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" wmode="window" allowfullscreen="true" width="470" height="353">
        </object>
        </p>
```

Ошибка:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как исправить?

Comment: "Вы ещё используете FLASH - тогда мы идём к вам (с топором)" )) а если серьёзно,  зачем вы вставляете видео через <object> ? почему не вставить просто по <iframe> который даёт сам VK ?

Comment: А если серьезно, то не хватает обязательных атрибутов `type="" и data=""`

Comment: можно почитать тут https://webref.ru/html/object   и тут  https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTML/Element/object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apache

```
Header always set X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN
```

Nginx

```
add_header X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN;
```